# How do I put students names from a CSV file into a List when printing

Tags: python

When printing I am trying to make it so I can put the Student Names and Details from a CSV with their calculated UCAS score into a new CSV file but I am having trouble printing this out.

For example I am trying to turn this:

- Jonah Whale 63.96900000000001 ['Forename: ','Surname: ','Ucas Points:
  ']
- Into this:  ['Forename: Jonah ','Surname: Whale ','Ucas
  Points:63.96900000000001 ']

How would I get the information to sit inside of the Forename, Surname and Ucas Points instead of printing it underneath.

An example from the Grades .csv file:

Forename,Surname, Grades

Bill,Smith,P,P,P,M,P,D,D,P,M,P

```
with open('Grades.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    with open('Results.csv', 'w') as f:
        fieldnames = ['Forename', 'Surname', 'Ucas Points']
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

information = ['Forename: ','Surname: ','Ucas Points: ']

students = []

for studentLine in data[1::]:
    students.append(studentLine.replace("\n", "").split(","))

for student in students:
    line_count = 0
    ucas = 0
    for index in student[4::]:
        if line_count == 7:
            if index == "P":
                ucas += 9 * 1.066
            elif index == "M":
                ucas += 9 * 2.133
            else:
                ucas += 9 * 3.2

        else:
            if index == "P":
                ucas += 6 * 1.066
            elif index == "M":
                ucas += 6 * 2.133
            else:
                ucas += 6 * 3.2
        line_count += 1

    print(student[0] + " " + student[1] + " " + str(ucas))
    print(information)
```

Comment: Would you mind please providing a couple of example lines of your `Results.csv` and `Grades.csv` file please.

Comment: Looks like you want a dictionary rather than a list: `{'Forename': 'Jonah', 'Surname': ...}`

Comment: I edited the post to include an example from the Grades.csv file the Forename, Surname and Grades are headers and the Name of the student and the grades after the name are the UCAS points which have been worked out in my code, The results.csv File is a file which the Forename, Surname and UcasTotal is going to be written into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code it should help.

```
with open('Grades.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

with open('Results.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Forename', 'Surname', 'Ucas Points']
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

information = ['Forename: ','Surname: ','Ucas Points: ']

students = []

res  = []

for studentLine in data[1::]:
    students.append(studentLine.replace("\n", "").split(","))

for student in students:
    cur_dic = {}
    line_count = 0
    ucas = 0
    for index in student[4::]:
        if line_count == 7:
            if index == "P":
                ucas += 9 * 1.066
            elif index == "M":
                ucas += 9 * 2.133
            else:
                ucas += 9 * 3.2

        else:
            if index == "P":
                ucas += 6 * 1.066
            elif index == "M":
                ucas += 6 * 2.133
            else:
                ucas += 6 * 3.2
        line_count += 1
    
    cur_dic['Forename'] = student[0]
    cur_dic['Surname'] = student[1]
    cur_dic['Ucas Points'] = str(ucas)
    res.append(cur_dic)  # in case you want to use all the data at once 
    print(cur_dic)
```